# understanding IO Completion Ports

Tags: sockets, winapi, io-completion-ports

I don't have this clear, I read somewhere that `GetQueuedCompletionStatus` will return `WSARecv` and `WSASend` results in the order they were created, so here is my question:
In a server If initialized `CreateIoCompletionPort` with `NumberOfConcurrentThreads = 1` then open a connection with one client and the server calls first `WSARecv` then `WSASend`, but the client never sends anything. In the server, will `GetQueuedCompletionStatus` never return the result from `WSASend` because a result from `WSARecv` has to happen first?

Comment: in what question at all and how IOCP here related ? you need call WSASend only after WSARecv complete ? or how/what logic ?

Comment: *I read somewhere that GetQueuedCompletionStatus will return WSARecv and WSASend results in the order they were created*  - no.  Results are returned in the order that the I/O completes.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is based on a false assumption.

Answer (score 1):

when IO operation complete(with success or initially return pending) on File with binded IOCP - packet queued to IOCP - and GetQueuedCompletionStatus got this packet. so if you begin 2 io operations - WSARecv and WSASend and WSASend compete first - GetQueuedCompletionStatus first return with WSASend status, even if  WSARecv not complete. so GetQueuedCompletionStatus just after some io operation complete on file with this IOCP